# Custom Python logging formatter works with fileConfig but not with dictConfig?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure out why these two logging configs, which as far as I can tell should be 100% identical, are not resulting in the same behavior:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'gunicorn.access': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['access_console'],
        'propagate': False,
        'qualname': 'gunicorn.access',
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stderr',
            'formatter': 'syslog',
        },
        'access_console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'docker_access',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'syslog': {
            '()': 'citi.logging.DockerFormatter',
            'fmt': 'SYSLOG %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
        },
        'docker_access': {
            '()': 'citi.logging.DockerFormatter',
            'fmt': 'GUNICORN_ACCESS %(asctime)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
}
```

```
[loggers]
keys=root,gunicorn.access

[handlers]
keys=console,access_console

[formatters]
keys=syslog,docker_access

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console

[logger_gunicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=access_console
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.access

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=syslog
args=(sys.stderr, )

[handler_access_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=docker_access
args=(sys.stdout, )

[formatter_syslog]
class=citi.logging.DockerFormatter
format=SYSLOG %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s

[formatter_docker_access]
class=citi.logging.DockerFormatter
format=GUNICORN_ACCESS %(asctime)s %(message)s
```

When I use `logging.config.fileConfig` and pass it the file that contains the second code block, it works fine. The `gunicorn.access` logger changes its formatter to the custom `DockerFormatter` class (which is a simple subclass of `logging.Formatter`) with the specified `format` string. The access logs look like this:

```
GUNICORN_ACCESS 2021-07-16 18:59:56,454 172.18.0.1 - - "GET /citi/server-status HTTP/1.0" 200 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 11766
```

But when I use `logging.config.dictConfig` and pass it the dict at the top, everything *except* the custom formatter works. The formatter appears to remain set to the original defaults provided by Gunicorn (maybe??). The output is:

```
172.18.0.1 - - "GET /citi/server-status HTTP/1.0" 200 11 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" 7549
```

By using the `logging_tree` package, I can tell that `gunicorn.access`'s formatter is some sort of default when using `dictConfig`. It *should* look like this:

```
   o<--"gunicorn"
   |   Level NOTSET so inherits level INFO
   |   |
   |   o   "gunicorn.access"
   |   |   Level INFO
   |   |   Propagate OFF
   |   |   Handler Stream <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
   |   |     Formatter <citi.logging.DockerFormatter object at 0x7f68240e7d90>
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
   o<--"gunicorn"
   |   Level NOTSET so inherits level INFO
   |   |
   |   o   "gunicorn.access"
   |   |   Level INFO
   |   |   Propagate OFF
   |   |   Handler Stream <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
   |   |     Formatter fmt='%(message)s' datefmt=None
```

The only difference I can detect in terms of how the `DockerFormatter` class is called is that the `fileConfig` form calls it with positional arguments, while `dictConfig` calls it with (correct) keyword arguments.

What appears to be happening is that the formatter is being constructed correctly, but not *assigned* correctly. And I can't figure out WHY.

The most infuriating thing is that I've actually simplified my logging config quite a bit. In my full config, I set up a custom `structlog`-based formatter, configured in exactly the same manner as `syslog` and `docker_access` are with `DockerFormatter`, but it DOES work. I am **very** frustrated. >_<

Answer (score 1):

And of course, my final, last ditch effort before leaving the office for the day (several hours late...) actually works. Turns out I was right about Gunicorn's default settings staying in place, because I had completely missed the absolutely essential `'loggers'` subdict in my dictConfig dictionary.

It's supposed to look this THIS:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'loggers' {
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['access_console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'qualname': 'gunicorn.access',
        },
    }
   ...
```